# How to authenticate with Google Service Account credentials using Postman and HTTPS?

Tags: google-api, postman, google-oauth, google-authentication, service-accounts

I have read these documents:

- https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started?hl=ru#auth-cloud-implicit-java
- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries?hl=ru
- https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production?hl=ru#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually
- https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#callinganapi

I have stored the google-secrets.json credentials of the service account.
However I can't understand how to send the request with the credentials to get the auth token or api key.

There are only libraries published that do this.

How do I setup authentication with HTTPS in Postman?

Answer (score 6):

This is answered very well by Gordon Thompson in the medium article [Google Authentication with Postman](https://medium.com/kinandcartacreated/google-authentication-with-postman-12943b63e76a) covering three different methods:

- Using oauth2l CLI
- Configuring Postman with OAuth 2 and User Credentials
- Configuring Postman to use a pre-request script. This will auto-generate Google Access and ID tokens from a Service Account key and save it in Postman. Based on the work of Denis Loginov, the gist is available [here](https://gist.github.com/dinvlad/425a072c8d23c1895e9d345b67909af0):

Answer (score 2):

In the Postman application

1. Go to *Environments* module and create a new environment. Let's call it *gcp_sa_env*
2. Create a new variable named *serviceAccountKey* and copy-paste the content of your *google-secrets.json* in its value. The JSON should contain items like `client_email`, `private_key`, `token_uri`
3. Go to *Collections* module and create a new request
4. Select the created environment (*gcp_sa_env*) at top-right
5. In the *Pre-request Script* copy-paste this Javascript code ([gist](https://gist.github.com/dinvlad/425a072c8d23c1895e9d345b67909af0)) enabling to auto-generates a Google OAuth token from a service account key
6. Add or remove scopes as needed in the `SCOPES` variable (see documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes))
7. In the *Authorization* module, select *Bearer Token* as the authorization type and write `{{accessToken}}` as *Token*
8. Configure the rest of the request (method, url, body, etc) and run it

Comment: Regarding Step 7) Postman complains that {{accessToken}} doesn't exist. Ignore the warning, it's created by the script.

Answer (score 1):

found.

signed it with RS256 on JWT.io with params

HEADER:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "your_private_key_id"
}
```

PAYLOAD:

```
{
  "iss": "your_client_email_of_service_account",
  "sub": "your_client_email_of_service_account",
  "aud": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
  "iat": current_unix_time,
  "exp": current_unix_time+3600
}
```

VERIFY SIGNATURE

your_private_key in last field (without \n)

got encoded key

and then

```
POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1

Host: www.googleapis.com

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Cache-Control: no-cache

grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=ENCODED_KEY_FROM_JWT.IO
```

and i got response

```
{

    "access_token": "ya21.c.ElrSBodwuWANeh7Q0-zlXpOxqm9-uEszPElsY2tvoG5aPxRgOkasN5G2sMgj3iosPVbRYk1wXw_DcBnm2FtuNBlZpv_wCC0YS5pWMykR8Ouf5CZg-8OK842rvfk",

    "expires_in": 3600,

    "token_type": "Bearer"

}
```

also dont forget give a priveleges to your service account for read in storage

Comment: I would love a bit more info on how you used Jwt.io to create your token.

Comment: I am getting invalid JWT signature. What could be the reason, I have followed the above approach to Authenticate and Access Google Spread Sheets from Postman and from MS Power Automate too.

I have the above details to authenticate, such as : private_key, private_key_id, client_email, client_id

But I am clueless to authorize Google Spread Sheet API and consume the services.

"auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",

Any help would be much appreciated and thank you in advance!