# How to authenticate with a Vertex AI endpoint in Postman without manual action?

Tags: authentication, postman, google-cloud-endpoints, service-accounts, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I created a endpoint on Google Cloud Platform Vertex AI and I managed to consume it with Postman with the following authentication process:

1. Connect to GCP
2. Open a gcloud console and run `gcloud auth login`
3. Follow the process to authenticate yourself as user of the Google Cloud SDK
4. Run `gcloud auth print-access-token`
5. Copy the returned token and paste it onto Postman > Authorization > Type > Bearer Token

[image]

**This token is only valid one hour**.

How can I remove this repetitive manual authentication ?
Could you describe another process for setting up automatic authentication ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a documentation about token's lifetime [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/token-types#at-lifetime).

> By default, access tokens are good for 1 hour (3,600 seconds). When the access token has expired, your token management code must get a new one.
>
> If you need an access token with a longer or shorter lifetime, you can use the serviceAccounts.generateAccessToken method to create the token. This method enables you to choose the lifetime of the token, with a maximum lifetime of 12 hours.

Comment: From 1 hour to 12 hours, the issue remains: I need to run again the shell command manually every 12 hours.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the best way is to define a service account (SA), use its key (which never expires) and a Javascript pre-request script:

1. A devops engineer can create the custom user-manager SA and grants it the *aiplatform.endpoints.predict* permission (see tutorial [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/18783/how-to-allow-an-application-outside-gcp-to-consume-a-gcp-vertex-ai-endpoint/18784))
2. Configure Postman with the keys of the created service account and the pre-request script auto-generating a Bearer token (see tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55205823/how-to-authenticate-with-google-service-account-credentials-using-postman-and-ht/77586503))
3. Fill in the content of your request (method, url, body, etc) and run it